# Paginate two collections + infiniteScroll

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

i'm having a trouble trying to paginate a view with 2 collections, i will explain.
i am using infiniteScroll (infinite-scrollDOTcom)
i don't have code on controller that i can reutilize to show i try with arrays but for infiniteScroll only with ajax and adding a route for it, but i dont like that ideia.

**im trying to do something like this (pseudocode)**

```
data = CollectionA + CollectionB
//if i can do it, try to orderBy (but not the most important now)
data->orderBy('something')
data->paginate(x)
return view()->with('data', data)
```

**Controller (this is only to work with the infinite scroll for now):**

```
public function getGarantias()
    {
        $data = GarantiaCasa::all()->toBase()->merge(GarantiaCarro::all()->toBase())->sortBy('nome');
    $data = new Paginator($data, 1, 1);
    //dd($data);
    return view('administrador.garantias')
        ->with('garantias', $data);
    }
```

**infiniteScroll:**

```
function infiniteScroll(message) {
    var loading_options = {
        finishedMsg: "<div class='end-msg'>"+message+"</div>",
        msgText: "<div class='center'></div>",
        img: '/img/loading.gif'
    };

    $('#items').infinitescroll({
        loading : loading_options,
        navSelector : "#data .pagination",
        nextSelector : "#data .pagination li.active + li a",
        itemSelector : "#items tr.item"
    });
}
```

**View (the 2 foreach is only for now until new solution**

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body" id="data">
      <div class="pull-right" onload="">
        @foreach(Auth::user()->getAllSeguros() as $tiposeguro)
        <div class="btn-group">
          <span type="button" class="btn btn-default  btn-filter" data-target="{{ $tiposeguro }}" >{{ ucfirst($tiposeguro) }}</span>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  btn-filter" data-target="all">Todos</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-container">
        <table class="table table-filter">
          <tbody id="items">
            @foreach($garantiasCarro as $garantia)
            <tr class="item" data-status="{{ $garantia->tipo }}" style="width: 500px">
              <td>
                <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                  <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/buttons/edit.png" class="media-photo">
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                  <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/buttons/delete.png" class="media-photo">
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="title">
                      {{ $garantia->nome }}
                      <span class="pull-right tipo">({{ $garantia->tipo }})</span>
                    </h4>
                    <p class="summary">{{ $garantia->descricao }}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div hidden="hidden">{{ $garantias->links() }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: now with the new Paginator i have sort of what i need but cant paginate, the infinitescroll doesnt work i think is probably because the links..
Thanks.

Comment: So you want to merge two collections ?

Comment: ohhh, i resolve my own question i need to Model1::all()->toBase()->merge(Model2::all()->toBase())

Comment: but i can't sort or order...

Comment: You have missed the keyword merge my friend ;)

Comment: Your solution's not working because if you have 2 Models with the same ID the first will be erased.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH oh yes is not working.. i cant paginate, how i can resolve this but dont touch on the tables?

Comment: Try `$sorted = $data->sortBy....` !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH now with the $data = Model1::all()->toBase()->merge(Model2::all()->toBase()) im doing $data = new Paginator($data, 1, 1); but when i do the links the infinitescroll dont work...

Comment: Try to use `$data->forPage()`.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH but the method forPage is not LengthAwarePaginator i dont have the links and just returns an array.